# Adding Numbers for Top 10 Post

Tags: css

Below you can see an image which shows you what I am trying to achieve how ever with the method I am using currently it just shows up as 1 for every number.. I am not sure how to achieve this different number for every post.

Here's the current HTML I have but I am assuming what I want is something with CSS to change that number?

```
<div id="top_songs_section" class="item_box module">
    <h2 class="heading_title">Top Singles</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span class="rank">1</span>
            <div class="info">
                <div class="desc">
                    <a href="/s/26849/White_Iverson__Remix___feat__French_Montana___Rae_Sremmurd_" title="Post Malone - White Iverson (Remix) (feat. French Montana & Rae Sremmurd)">
                        <p class="title">White Iverson (Remix) (feat. French Montana & Rae Sremmurd)</p>
                        <p class="artist">Post Malone</p>
                    </a>
                    <a class="play btn song" song_id="26849" song_version_id="" album_id="" title="Post Malone - White Iverson (Remix) (feat. French Montana & Rae Sremmurd)">play</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>                  
    </ul>
    <div class="sub_title group">
        <a class="see_all_btn" href="/most_popular">See all</a>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: How can you even expect this could change using CSS? CSS is only for presentation, not content.

Comment: @PraveenKumar it can change using CSS. There's actually a couple news websites I have seen that change the number of the span, and then grab that number and echo it out in PHP. So you're actually sort of incorrect.

Comment: @Ritzy I do know about `counter` and `content`, but this is absurd.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Why not just help the dude out? I am not sure how to achieve this or I would do so my self.. I am looking into it now though.

Comment: @Ritzy Well, yeah the same thing. Very tough to achieve it. So, I better leave it to you guys. `:)` Even I am not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Why would you not just use `Javascript` or `PHP` to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may acheive this with counter.
Example of css

```
ul {
  counter-reset: counter1;
}
ul li:before {
  content: counter(counter1);
  counter-increment: counter1;
}
```

Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9dcfjpnu/

Browser support is good http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-counters

P.S. I changed `p` to `span` in links in `.desc` as putting block level elements in link is considered bad practice.

P.P.S. You can more easily achieve this with `<ol>` instead of `<ul>`, so it is better to use answer by repzero if you can.

Comment: After tinkering with this, I have this in my fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/fr3k11ht/1/ it seems to just repeat as 1?

Comment: @Placeholder you should add `counter-reset` to `ul` or some specific element. With css in your fiddle you reset counter for every li and it starts from 1 again. Check this explanation on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters

Comment: I am very confused.. In your example, you removed the `<span class="rank"></span>` element which is where I want the number to be displayed... but when I put the code which should display it, it does not? Help please?

Comment: @Placeholder Counters are used with `content` property which exists with `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements. Hovever this pseudo-elements may be styled just like any other elements i.e. `display:block; font-weight:bold; color:#ccc;`

Comment: So I can't use this with my span tag?... Literally in the fiddle I showed you the numbers display.. but it's not putting it past number 1? How can I fix this? I already know about styling..

Comment: @Placeholder I modified your fiddle a little: https://jsfiddle.net/fr3k11ht/3/ Is it correctly displaying now?

Answer (score 1):

replace all your `<p>` tags with a list tag and style with css

```
li {
  list-style-type:decimal;
}
```

here is a snippet

```css
li {
  list-style-type:decimal;
}
```

```html
<div id="top_songs_section" class="item_box module">
<h2 class="heading_title">Top Singles</h2>
<ul>
<li>
<span class="rank">1</span>
<div class="info">
<div class="desc">
<a href="/s/26849/White_Iverson__Remix___feat__French_Montana___Rae_Sremmurd_" title="Post Malone - White Iverson (Remix) (feat. French Montana & Rae Sremmurd)">
<li class="title">White Iverson (Remix) (feat. French Montana & Rae Sremmurd)</li>
<li class="artist">Post Malone</li>
</a>
<li class="play btn song" song_id="26849" song_version_id="" album_id="" title="Post Malone - White Iverson (Remix) (feat. French Montana & Rae Sremmurd)">play</li>
</div>
</div>
</li>

</ul>
<div class="sub_title group">
<a class="see_all_btn" href="/most_popular">See all</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try validating your HTML. `:)`